# Angular-meteor ORM-like one-to-many relationship without infinite-digest issues

Tags: angular-meteor

I'm working on a User-Roles relationship, and my code works except that it produces an infinite digest error on the Angular side, which I think has some performance implications.  In my User class (ES2015), I have:

```
get roles() {
  return Roles.findByIds(this._roleIds).fetch()
}
```

And the problem is that the above getter returns a new object every time, so in Angular's eyes, they're not equal.  I tried `track by`, as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="role in user.roles track by role._id">
    {{role.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

which throws the following exception:

`Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":20,"oldVal":19}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":21,"oldVal":20}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":22,"oldVal":21}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":23,"oldVal":22}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":24,"oldVal":23}]]`

Without `track by`, I see longer stacktraces, mentioning "Administrator"

`Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":9,"oldVal":8},{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":"Administrator"}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":10,"oldVal":9},{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":"Administrator"}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":11,"oldVal":10},{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":"Administrator"}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":12,"oldVal":11},{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":"Administrator"}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":13,"oldVal":12},{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":"Administrator"}]]`

So for now, my options are avoiding the getter, and having an `updateRoles` method like so:

```
updateRoles() {
  this.roles = Roles.findByIds(this._roleIds).fetch()
}
```

This gets rid of the exception, but it seems that I have to call `updateRoles` manually everytime the `_roleIds` array changes.  I just want to know if there is a better approach compared to those I have mentioned above.

Comment: I'd love to help, but admittedly, I'm a tad confused on what you're trying to do. what is get roles() supposed to be doing? And, I'm assuming you're suing alanning:meteor-roles (no?) which creates a roles array on the user object, but only contains the string name.

Comment: I'm not using `alanning:roles` since it does not support hierarchical roles the last time I checked.  I'm doing my app in an ORM-ish style where let's say you have a "one person has many pets" relationship, you can just say `person.pets`, etc.

I have solved this just yesterday by making a `Model` superclass that dynamically makes idempotent getters for the relationships you define.

It's a solution similar to this comment:  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/705#issuecomment-36737595

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to make the getter idempotent.  It should return the **same** roles array when given the same `_roleIds`

Here's my shot at solving this.  I used an idea similar to this Github comment:  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/705#issuecomment-36737595

The idea is to define the getter using `Object.defineProperty` or (ES2015) `Reflect.defineProperty`, such that the getter will be idempotent.

```
Reflect.defineProperty(this, "roles", {
  get: Model._makeIdempotent(this, "_roleIds", () => {
    return Roles.find({_id: {$in: this._roleIds}}).fetch()
  }),
})
```

Though I don't use the above approach manually in my own codes, and `Reflect.define...` gets called in a loop for every "foreign key", but that's the general idea.